# How to pass errors from one action to another

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

How can I pass the modelstate errors from oneaction to another in the case of the  Action Delete?

```
  public ActionResult Index()
    {
        ProjectTestModel model = new ProjectTestModel ();
        return GetProjectView(model);

    }

    public ActionResult GetProjectView(ProjectTestModel model)
    {
        return View("Index", model);
    }

 public ActionResult Delete(int id)
    {
        try
        {
           test.Load(id)
            test.Delete();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        catch (Exception e)
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("Error", e.Message);
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is common to return the view on error and redirect when successful.

```
public ActionResult Delete(int id)
{
    try
    {
        test.Load(id);
        test.Delete();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

    catch (Exception e)
    {
        ModelState.AddModelError("Error", e.Message);
        return View("Index");
    }
}
```

Comment: Why should I laod myModel? Isnt` there any other way?  I don`t really like the idea of laoding myModel as I won`t be using the values from myModel afterwards

Comment: No, it is not required to load myModel, the above was just an example. If you do not need to populate any fields then returning myModel is not necessary.  I've updated the answer to make this clearer.

Answer (score 4):

You may consider using [TempData](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-en/library/system.web.mvc.controllerbase.tempdata.aspx) to pass an error message.

Comment: Should we empty TempData after handling the 2nd view?

Comment: Cool, MVC is cool :), this is an MVC feature right? I mean it is not a normal .Net garbage collection.